# Which error handling pattern is better: one try/catch around large block of code and many try/catches around smaller blocks of code?

Tags: error-handling

This is a question about style. Which one of these patterns is a better way of handling errors?

Pattern #1:

```
Try {
  function1();
} catch (err) {
  console.log(‘function1() threw the following error:’, err);
}

Try {
  function2();
} catch (err) {
  console.log(‘function2() threw the following error:’, err);
}

Try {
  function3();
} catch (err) {
  console.log(‘function3() threw the following error:’, err);
}
```

Pattern #2:

```
Try {
  function1();
  function2();
  function3();
} catch (err) {
  console.log(‘The following error was thrown:’, err);
}
```

I find pattern #1 to be way more specific and you can log exactly where/why the error happened (i.e. ‘function1() throw an error…’). True, you could rely on the error message in err but that’s not always helpful (ex. ‘Cannot reference prop of undefined’ doesn’t tell you which function that came from).

Pattern #2 on the other hand is a lot more succinct (i.e. less code, more easily maintained) but at the cost of specificity.

Is there a reason one pattern is better than the other or is it just a matter of personal preference?

Answer (score 1):

Generally I break my try/catches by idea just for reading clarification, similar to a function. Both methods have almost identical runtime speeds so for efficiency, both are acceptable. It is always better to have the errors be specific. My try/catch blocks often look like

```
try {
    function1();
    function2();
    function3();
} catch (err1) {
    console.log(‘The following error was thrown:’, err);
} catch (err2) {
    console.log(‘The following error was thrown:’, err);
} catch (all) {
    console.log(‘The following error was thrown:’, err);
}
```

Comment: Back your usage with reasonable explaination